# Manual Compile of Netbeans Java Swing Application Created Multiple Classes

Tags: user-interface, swing, compiler-construction

I created a Swing GUI using netbeans, and when I try to manually do the following:

```
# ls
myProg.form     myProg.java

# javac myProg.java
# ls
myProg$1.class  myProg$2.class myProg$3.class myProg$4.class myProg$5.class myProg$6.class myProg.class myProg.form myProg.java
```

It created those extra classes.  Why is this happening? Is this a fluke? I tried Googling but no answers have shown up.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to know there's nothing wrong there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those extra classes are anonymous inner classes used by your Swing GUI. The java compiler names anonymous inner classes in such a manner.